# Find 10 "main()" in first 10 lines in regular files

Tags: text-processing, grep

Trying to write a comand that prints these of its parameters, which correspond to
regular files containing text “main()” in any of its first 10 lines.

What i should you to scan all files, and look for 10 first lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avail yourself the GNU grep with it's Perl regexes also.
This will output the line containing the string main() anywhere in the first 10 lines of the input file.

The `-z` option allows the file to be slurped and treated as one big string (as long as it doesn't contain NUL characters)  on which grep is to operate. The `-P` enables the Perl mode of grep, `-o` shows you the matching portion, `-h` will hide the filename from being displayed alongside the matching line, and `-l` will list the filename only.

In case you wanted both the filename and matching line:

```
grep -HPoz  '\A(.*\n){0,9}\K[^\n]*main\(\)[^\n]*\n' file.txt
```

only matching line:

```
grep -hPoz '\A(.*\n){0,9}\K[^\n]*main\(\)[^\n]*\n' file.txt
```

(the `-h` being only necessary when there's more than one file)

filename only:

```
grep -Pozl '\A(.*\n){0,9}\K[^\n]*main\(\)[^\n]*\n' file.txt
```

To run over the current directory but without recursing: (ofc, the grep options need to supplied as per requirements as shown above)

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type f \
  -exec grep -HPoz '\A(.*\n){0,9}\K[^\n]*main\(\)[^\n]*\n' {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search the first ten lines of multiple files for a pattern, you can do:

```
for file in *; do 
    head -n 10 "$file" | grep -F 'main()' 
done
```

That will print the matching lines. To print both the matching line and the file name, use:

```
for file in *; do 
    q=$(head -n 10 "$file" | grep -F 'main()')
    [ -z "$q" ] || printf '%s : %s\n' "$file" "$q"
done
```

And to print only the file names and not the matching line:

```
for file in *; do 
    head -n 10 "$file" | grep -qF 'main()' && printf '%s\n' "$file" 
done
```

Comment: @don_crissti i) eek! Thanks, fixed. ii) Uhm, because I completely forgot to add the `\n`. Thanks again and fixed again.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR <= 10 && index($0, "main()") {print FILENAME ":", $0}' ./*.c
```